# Jnlp: NOT VERIFIED

Tags: java, jnlp

So I have been able to launch my Java application with .jnlp with success. All the Jars are properly signed.

However, when it asks the user to run the application, it says

(NOT VERIFIED) My Software

in the Vendor section.

How can I remove the NOT VERIFIED message.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the "NOT VERIFIED", use a certificate that can be verified. That is to say a certificate signed by a recognised root CA (or delegate) rather than self-signed.

Comment: I'm not going to recommend a particular CA. There's a rather incomplete [but you can help expand it] list on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Certificate_authorities

Comment: (Note there are different kinds of certificates. You'll need a code signing certificate.)

Answer (score 1):

The certificates will have to be signed by a certificate authority.